# Staying in Europe between two Schengen visas

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

My friend is traveling in Europe (Italy, France) and she has two Schengen visas - the current one from Greece that expires on June 23, and the new one, also Greek, that starts on June 24 (thus she doesn't have a gap).

I can't find any info on whether she has to leave Schengen on 23rd and then re-enter on 24th thru Greece, or if she can just stay in Italy (she is way below 90/180 days).

I would like to get a link to any official web site that states that it's fine to stay in Schengen zone between two consequent visas.

Comment: What kind of visa does she have? Are both visas type C?

Comment: @xngtng both Schengen tourist visa with multi entry. I assume it's type C

Comment: Please add that information to the question (both visas are multiple-entry visas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or if she can just stay in Italy (she is way below 90/180 days).

A new **multiple-entry visa** [MEV] should always start directly after the previous one, if issued before the first one expires.

The sample given in **Visa Code Handbook** covers your friends situation exactly.

She can enter with the first and leave with the second as long as the 90 days is not exceeded.

> **Visa Code Handbook**, Chapter 8.3 ([page 77 of 2020 pdf](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/document/download/bb6e2b52-2d20-4877-806c-374f64ec6735_en))
>
> Holders of a valid MEV may be issued a new **multiple-entry visa** with a long validity provided that the validity of the new visa starts at the expiry of the previous one and the existing valid visa should not be revoked. Responsibility for complying with the 90/180-day rule lies with the visa holder.
>
> > Example: A Moroccan lawyer representing a gender equality NGO who frequently participates in meetings in various Member States holds a multiple-entry visa which expires on 31.5. She applies for a new visa on 15.4.
> > If a new visa is issued, it should be valid from 1.6. and in such a case the visa holder would be entitled to **enter the territory of the Member States on the basis of the first visa that will expire during the stay and leave on the basis of the new visa**.